# Object identity in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

How to check that two variables point to the same object? Meaning that if I mutate it—the value pointed to by both variables will change. In Python there is `is` operator, what about JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the strict equality operator (`===`) will evaluate to true if references are the same without doing any type conversion:

```
var a, b, c;
a = {};
b = {};
c = a;
console.log( a === b ); //false
console.log( a === c ); //true
```

---

After shooting down two posts that have made the same mistakes, I think I should point out that it's possible for `==` to equate a reference type with a value type due to type conversion:

```
var a, b;
a = {
    toString: function () {
        return 'foo';
    }
};
b = 'foo';
console.log( a == b ); //true
console.log( a === b ); //false
```

AFAIK if you can guarantee that both variables are reference types, `==` should work just fine, but that is so rarely the case that you're better off sticking with strict comparison most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent operator in Javascript is "===".

Similarly, "!==" is the same as "is not" in Python.